# Multiple apps in Vue.js v3 using vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I'm trying to build a site that will have different apps based on the role of the user.
The initial idea is having 3 apps.
The first one is the general one. Here you'll find the login page, a registration form, forgot password.
When the user logs in, I check his role and send him to the right app (admin, client, supplier).
I want to share many components between the apps, but keeping the screens layouts independently.

Here is my site structure (it can be improved):

```
/index.html - (General app) - It will load the general app with a <router-view> to render the other general site components
/Register - (General app) - Form for the user registers to the site. It should render in the "index.html" <router-view>
/ForgotPass - (General app) - Recover you pass. It should render in the "index.html" <router-view>
/Admin/index.html - (Admin app) - Index page for the admin page. It will have its own router and a <router-view> element
/Admin/Dashboard - (Admin app) - Component to render into the "/Admin/index.html" <router-view>
/Client/index.html - (Client app) - Index page for the admin page. It will have its own router and a <router-view> element
/Client/Dashboard - (Client app) - Component to render into the "/Admin/index.html" <router-view>
```

And my folders structure is:

```
├─ components/
│  ├─ SharedComponent1.vue
│  ├─ SharedComponent2.vue
├─ sites/
│  ├─ admin/
│  │  ├─ adminApp.vue
│  │  ├─ index.html
│  │  ├─ main.js
│  │  ├─ router.js
│  ├─ clients/
│  │  ├─ clientsApp.vue
│  │  ├─ index.html
│  │  ├─ main.js
│  │  ├─ router.js
├─ App.vue
├─ main.js
├─ router.js
index.html
vue.config.js
```

My problem is when I want to redirect the user to /sites/admin (or /sites/admin/index.html) and make the browser to load the new app from /sites/admin/index.html, vue-router tries to find that path in the paths list to render it in the /index.html  element. It can't find the path and fails.

Is there any way to do that?
The main goal is having independent apps for those roles but sharing components. If I need any change to for deploying it to prod, please let me know.

Comment: Why would you hate yourself so much? You can simply have one router and different components.

Comment: I'm just playing with the idea. I see each app growing and I like the idea of letting them run independently.

Comment: You can grow them independently by having different components.